# Angular Module Routing not working

Tags: angularjs, module, routes

Here's my code:
**app.js**

```js
var app = angular.module('groceryListApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "views/groceryList.html"
      controller: "GroceryListItemsController"
    })
});

app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.appTitle = "Grocery List";
}]);

app.controller("GroceryListItemsController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.groceryItems = [{
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'milk',
      date: '2017-10-01'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'cookies',
      date: '2017-10-02'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'ice cream',
      date: '2017-10-03'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'potatoes',
      date: '2017-10-04'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'cereal',
      date: '2017-10-05'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'bread',
      date: '2017-10-06'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'eggs',
      date: '2017-10-07'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'tortillas',
      date: '2017-10-08'
    }
  ]
}]);
```

and **index.html** is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="groceryListApp">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeController">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="color: #5bdb46">
        </span> {{appTitle}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container" ng-view>

  </div>

  <script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**groceryList.html**   is

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <a href="#/addItem" style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Grocery Item </a>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="item in groceryItems | orderBy: 'date'" class="list-group-item text-center clearfix">
      <span style="font-weight: bold">{{item.itemName | uppercase}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When running index.html in chrome the output is {{appTitle}}. I assume the `ngRoute` isn't being recognized here. Please help.

All the lib files are correctly in place too.

The grocery list is supposed to be visible. It had worked without the routing mechanism

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your order **`angular.min.js`** should be loaded ahead of **`lib/angular-route.min.js`**

```
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Anything else i can do?

Comment: you are also missing ng-view

Comment: no, the view is correct, but items are not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is definitely with the sequence of the scripts. So here's what I did.

```js
var app = angular.module('groceryListApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "../views/groceryList.html",
      controller: "GroceryListItemsController"
    })
});

app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.appTitle = "Grocery List";
}]);

app.controller("GroceryListItemsController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.groceryItems = [{
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'milk',
      date: '2017-10-01'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'cookies',
      date: '2017-10-02'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'ice cream',
      date: '2017-10-03'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'potatoes',
      date: '2017-10-04'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'cereal',
      date: '2017-10-05'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'bread',
      date: '2017-10-06'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'eggs',
      date: '2017-10-07'
    },
    {
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'tortillas',
      date: '2017-10-08'
    }
  ]
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="groceryListApp">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeController">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="color: #5bdb46">
       </span> {{appTitle}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container" ng-view>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
  <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**groceryList.html**

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <a href="#/addItem" style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Grocery Item </a>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="item in groceryItems | orderBy: 'date'" class="list-group-item text-center clearfix">
      <span style="font-weight: bold">{{item.itemName | uppercase}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since I didn't have most of the code, I just created this bare minimum project from the code that you supplied and served it using [this Web Server](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)

And it works at my end:

[image]

I did use relative paths instead of absolute paths though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it partially helped.

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
   <h1>Add Item Below</h1>
  </div>
<form name="groceryForm">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder ="Grocery Item">
 </div>


 <div class="form-group">
  <a href="#/" class="btn btn-success btn lg btn-block">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
   Save
  </a>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group">
  <a href="#/" class="btn btn-default btn lg btn-block">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
   Cancel
  </a>
 </div>
</form>
</div>

Comment: after clicking add grocery item, page isnt getting redirected

Comment: But you didn't really provide the inputs in that regard in the question you asked, did you? We're not sure what controller will get activated when this `/addItem` route is going to load.

Comment: yes, all the code is present here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988207/angularjs-routing-multiple-redirection . Thanks !

Comment: Please do see it ! @Siddharth Ajmera